# Sails.js deployment issue on azure vm

Tags: node.js, azure, ssl, sails.js

I am deploying my sailsjs app using forever in windows azure. And it is taking forever to get my server up and running. Initally it was working fine when it was http but I changed to SSL with self signed certificate and things are not working at all. I tried forever list and it was showing my server was up and running but I can't knock my server at all. I tried to knock the server using curl and it was telling me port 443 connection refused. Can anyone help.

Comment: You azure VM is publicly accessible through a cloud service. That cloud service will have public ports managed by the load balancer for your service. Have you created a public port for https (port 443)?

Comment: I created endpoints but that was not the issue. The issue was deploying to linux below port 1024 as a regular user. Appearently I have to do it as a super user to solve it. Thanks though for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Deploying it as a Super user solves the problem. In linux when we deploy to a port below 1024 we need to have superuser access.